# RXJava how to wait/insert a subsequence

Tags: rx-java

I have a Sequence of Observable commands. The commands are executed sequential. Now one of these commands has to dynamically create a second Sequence of Observable commands when its executed. Before the first sequence continues with the next Observable, the second sequence has to be finished.
This looks like a merge in git (0 represents an observable command):

```
Seq1:   -0-0-0-0         0-0-0-0-
                \       /
Seq2:            0-0-0-0
```

I use concatEager() to achieve sequential execution within one Sequence. The problem is that the current execution looks like following (=> after subscribing to seq2 it is executed in parallel to seq1).

```
Seq1:   -0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-
                \       
Seq2:            0-0-0-0-
```

Is there a way to wait/block in the forth observable of seq1 until seq2 has finished? Or to merge after subscription of seq1?

Comment: The problem is that Seq1 is already subscribed() and its commands are emitted. One of the emitted commands creates a second Seq2 which needs to be merged into Seq1 or block the further execution of Seq1 until it is completed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `concatMap`. Something like

```
Observable.from(new Integer[]{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5})
          .concatMap( l -> {
            ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            temp.add(l);
            for (int i=0; i<l-1 ; i++) {
               temp.add(l);
            }
            return Observable.from(temp);
          })
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to ensure that two observable wait after the other finish is through merge, zip or even better concat

```
       @Test
public void testContact() {

    Observable.concat(Observable.just("Hello"),
                      Observable.just("reactive"),
                      Observable.just("world"))
              .subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

Take a look how the combining operators works

https://github.com/politrons/reactive